# How to use variable in mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb

data in "test":

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ddabe6855a0a250877cc92"), "id" : 2, "value" : { "20140501" : 10, "20140502" : 1, "20140503" : 2 }}
```

I can update in mongodb by this:

```
db.test.update({id:2}, {$set:{'value.20140501':12}})
```

But when I use python, I can't be sure this key('20140501').I want to use variable to replace '20140501'.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.test
table = db.test
date = '20140501'
table.find_one_and_update({'id':2}, {'$set': {"value.date":23423423}})
```

This is just not right.How to use variable in mongodb with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dict manipulation is basically the same as JavaScript, as used in your current notation it "stringifies".

Do this instead:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.test
table = db.test
date = '20140501'
update = { "$set": {} }
update['$set']['value.' + date] = 23423423
table.find_one_and_update({'id':2}, update)
```

Now the `update` object looks just like you want with the variable replaced in the key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
date = '20140501'
table.find_one_and_update({'id':2}, {'$set': {"value.{}".format(date):23423423}})
```